# Why was no intrinsic access to the CPU's status register in the design of both C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, language-design

In the case of the overflow flag, it would seem that access to this flag would be a great boon to cross-architecture programming. It would provide a safe alternative to relying on undefined behaviour to check for signed integer overflow such as:

```
if(a < a + 100) //detect overflow
```

I do understand that there are safe alternatives such as:

```
if(a > (INT_MAX - 100)) //detected overflow
```

However, it would seem that access to the status register or the individual flags within it is missing from both the C and C++ languages. Why was this feature not included or what language design decisions were made that prohibited this feature from being included?

Comment: C and C++ were meant to be portable. Not all processors have the same CPU status register(s).

Comment: Researching this question, I could not find record of a CPU not having an overflow flag. The intrinsic could be broken down into individual flag access, allowing it to be portable.

Comment: SSE operations don't have overflow flags. The compiler is allowed to implement things using SSE instructions.

Comment: While not strictly relevant to the answer to this question, I would argue that when C was initially designed there were no SSE instructions available so that problem did not influence the omission of this feature.

Comment: Irrelevant. It does not matter, in terms of portability, if there are or aren't CPUs without the flag. It's only relevant if they can or cannot be built.

Comment: @Timesquare: The fact that there could be architectures without a flag probably did influence the decisions even though the particular example of SSE did not. Are you sure that all platforms known at the time of the C standard did have underflow?

Comment: At the time of C's initial design, there were other things. Like CPUs that used one's complement, sign and absolute value and other peculiarities to implement signed arithmetics. All of which have completely different overflow semantics.

Comment: I once read an article about undefined behavior that talked about a machine that had an unusual architecture for dealing with overflow - I wish I could find that damn thing now.

Comment: @Timesquare *"when C was initially designed there were no SSE instructions available"* - Exactly! you don't want a language that is only portable for today's hardware, in times where hardware evolves at the pace of seconds (exaggeration intenional). Portable also means furture-prove. So you could say it indeed influenced the decision, even if not directly.

Comment: I used a language in about 1980 that had a $CARRY variable. However the question should be addressed to Dennis Ritchie. Anything you get here will be guesswork. Not constructive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Because C++ is designed as a portable language, i.e. one that compiles on many CPUs (e.g. x86, ARM, LSI-11/2, with devices like Game Boys, Mobile Phones, Freezers, Airplanes, Human Manipulation Chips and Laser Swords).

  - the available flags across CPUs may largely differ
  - even within the same CPU, flags may differ (take x86 scalar vs. vector instructions)
  - some CPUs may not even have the flag you desire at all
- The question has to be answered: *Should the compiler always deliver/enable that flag when it can't determine whether it is used at all?*, which does not conform the **pay only for what you use** unwritten but holy law of both C and C++
- Because compilers would have to be forbidden to optimize and e.g. reorder code to keep those flags valid

Example for the latter:

```
int x = 7;
x += z;
int y = 2;
y += z;
```

The optimizer may transform this to that pseudo assembly code:

```
alloc_stack_frame 2*sizeof(int)
load_int 7, $0
load_int 2, $1
add z, $0
add z, $1
```

which in turn would be more similar to

```
int x = 7;
int y = 2;
x += z;
y += z;
```

Now if you query registers inbetween

```
int x = 7;
x += z;
if (check_overflow($0)) {...}
int y = 2;
y += z;
```

then after optimizing and dissasembling you *might* end with this:

```
int x = 7;
int y = 2;
x += z;
y += z;
if (check_overflow($0)) {...}
```

which is then incorrect.

More examples could be constructed, like what happens with a constant-folding-compile-time-overflow.

---

Sidenotes: I remember an old Borland C++ compiler having a small API to read the current CPU registers. However, the argumentation above about optimization still applies.

On another sidenote: To check for overflow:

```
// desired expression: int z = x + y
would_overflow = x > MAX-y;
```

more concrete

```
auto would_overflow = x > std::numeric_limits<int>::max()-y;
```

or better, less concrete:

```
auto would_overflow = x > std::numeric_limits<decltype(x+y)>::max()-y;
```

Answer (score 8):

Because C and C++ are designed to be platform independent. Status register is not.

These days, two's complement is universally used to implement signed integer arithmetic, but it was not always the case. One's complement or sign and absolute value used to be quite common. And when C was first designed, such CPUs were still in common use. E.g. COBOL distinguishes negative and positive 0, which existed on those architectures. Obviously overflow behaviour on these architectures is completely different!

By the way, you *can't* rely on undefined behaviour for detecting overflow, because [reasonable compilers](http://gcc.gnu.org) upon seeing

```
if(a < a + 100)
```

will write a warning and compile

```
if(true)
```

... (provided optimizations are turned on and the particular optimization is not turned off).

And note, that you can't rely on the warning. The compiler will only emit the warning when the condition ends up `true` or `false` after equivalent transformations, but there are many cases where the condition will be modified in presence of overflow without ending up as plain `true`/`false`.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of the following reasons.

1. By allowing access to the register-flags, portability of the language across platforms is severily limited.
2. The optimizer can change expressions drastically, and render your flags useless.
3. It would make the language more complex
4. Most compilers have a big set of intrinsic functions, to do most common operations (e.g. addition with carry) without resorting to flags.
5. Most expressions can be rewritten in a safe way to avoid overflows.
6. You can always fall back to inline assembly if you have very specific needs

Access to status registers does not seem needed enough, to go through a standardization-effort.